# How to tell whether a complex sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

How do you tell whether a sequence with complex parts converges? For example, what would you do to prove whether the sequence $z_{n}=\frac{n}{(1+i)^{n}}$ converges?

Comment: Try showing $|z_n|$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|z_n| = n(1/\sqrt{2})^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $z_n \to 0$.

Comment: Sorry, why is $|z_{n}|=n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^{n}$?

Comment: It's because $$|z_n| = n\left|\frac{1}{1 + i}\right|^n = n\left(\frac{1}{|1 + i|}\right)^n = n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n$$